# Login page is not appearing when the session expires

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have one project developed using codeigniter

In that when session expires I need to redirect to the login page.
controller file

//inherit the parent constructor
        parent::__construct();

```
    //check whether it is an ajax call or not
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        //check the session exist or not
        $status = $this->common_functions->verify_session('ajax_call');

        //if session doesnot exist
        if(! $status)
        {               
            //return the json
            echo json_encode(array("session_timeout"=>"true", "msg"=>"<h3>Session timed out.</h3> Please login once again."));

            //exit
            exit;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        //Initialize the private property
        $this->_section = '';

        //check the session exist or not
        $this->common_functions->verify_session();

    }
```

And in common function

I have the code to redirect into login page

Comment: Can you please add what you have written in "common function".

Comment: In common function I have code to redirect the user into login page, I checked that code it works properly with other controller files

Comment: for ajax requests you'll have to use something like top.location.href='xxxxxxx' to redirect. Have you taken this into account?